# Is it possible to get button title from IB in class?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have several buttons with titles 0 - 9 and in my custom UIButton class I want to be able to use a switch to check the button title. The buttons are created in the storyboard. The UIButton class looks like:

```
protocol NumpadDelegate: class {
    func changeValue()
}

class NumpadButton: UIButton, NumpadDelegate {

    let initial = String()          // I want to assign the title of the button here
    var alternative = String()
    var change: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            let title = change ? alternative : initial
            setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }

    func changeValue() {
        change = !change
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that or I'll have to programmatically create the buttons? I'm trying to limit the use of a custom UIButton class so I don't have to create one for each of my buttons.

EDIT:

As requested, the code of when the button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func buttonNumber(sender: UIButton) {
        let value = sender.titleLabel!.text!

        switch value {
        case "C": orderLabel.text = ""
        default: orderLabel.text = orderLabel.text.map { count($0) < 10 ? $0 + value : $0 } ?? value
        }

        if let check = orderLabel.text {
            inputResult.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for index in 0..<items.count {
                let id = items[index].id
                if id.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(check.lowercaseString) {
                    inputResult += [items[index]]
                }
            }

            numpadTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I swipe the buttons I want their titles to change to an alternative `String` i.e. button with title 1 will change to A and button with title 2 will change to B.

Comment: Can you show us the button tapped method when button is tapped? Also are all the button calling the same method?

Comment: It looks like you've complicated it for no reason. If you want current title of the button, there's this property currentTitle on UIButton .

Comment: @KumarNitin It wouldn't be a problem if I create an outlet for each button to access the properties. But I'd like to avoid creating multiple outlets and instead I want to solve it by creating a custom class and handle things there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you're going for but here's an example where I've created outlets for each `NumpadButton` and added them to an `array`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button1: NumpadButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: NumpadButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: NumpadButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: NumpadButton!

var array: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    array.addObject(button1)
    array.addObject(button2)
    array.addObject(button3)
    array.addObject(button4)
}
```

Each button has a title of either "1", "2", "3" or "4". Then you can check the title via a case statement like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    for item in array {

        var button = item as! UIButton

        switch button.currentTitle! {
            case "1":
                println("This button has title of 1")
            case "2":
                println("This button has title of 2")
            case "3":
                println("This button has title of 3")
            case "4":
                println("This button has title of 4")
            default:
                println("default case")
        }
    }
}
```

}

This would be one way you could use a case statement to access the titles of `UIButtons` and then just adjust the application to whatever functionality you want (e.g. through an `IBAction`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted to avoid creating multiple outlets and solve it within the class declaration, i.e. getting the button title in the class and do stuff with it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning your buttons to a 'referencing outlet' in Interface Builder, assign them to a 'referencing outlet collection' which you can declare as

```
 @IBOutlet var buttons: [NumpadButton]
```